# Error connecting to MS SQL LocalDB through FireDac (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, localdb, firedac

Connection parameters:

```
Server=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB
DriverID=MSSQL
ODBCAdvanced=AttachDbFileName=C:\Dir\Dir\TestDB.mdf
```

connect is successful.

Requests like FDConnection.ExecSQLScalar('SELECT ....')  - work well
Requets through  TFDScript - work well

but running TFDQuery generates the following error:

```
[FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Could not find server 'C:\Dir\Dir\TestDB' in sys.servers.
Verify that the correct server name was specified. 
If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add Database=any_name to connection string.

```
Server=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB
DriverID=MSSQL
ODBCAdvanced=AttachDbFileName=C:\Dir\Dir\TestDB.mdf
Database=MyDatabase
```